# Update only by payload

Tags: mongodb, go

I am making rest API using go and echo, and I'm working on updating data. At first I was using struct to store the payload and then do the update to mongodb

```
type updatePayload struct {
    FullName    string `json:"fullName" bson:"fullName"`
    FirstName   string `json:"firstName" bson:"firstName"`
    LastName    string `json:"lastName" bson:"lastName"`
    Location    string `json:"location" bson:"location"`
    Gender      string `json:"gender" bson:"gender"`
    State       string `json:"state" bson:"state"`
    Subdistrict string `json:"subdistrict" bson:"subdistrict"`
    Address     string `json:"homeAddress" bson:"homeAddress"`
    Profession  string `json:"provession" bson:"provession"`
    Settings    struct {
        Email bool `json:"email" bson:"email"`
        SMS   bool `json:"sms" bson:"sms"`
        GCM   bool `json:"gcm" bson:"gcm"`
    } `json:"settings" bson:"settings"`
    Coordinates struct {
        Type        string    `json:"type" bson:"type"`
        Coordinates []float64 `json:"coordinates" bson:"coordinates"`
    } `json:"coordinates" bson:"coordinates"`
}
```

The update is working but if I'm not send all the parameters like only send one field , the rest of the fields is updated to, only it was an empty string ""

is there any way I can only update the field that was specified on the request payload.

Comment: Check out this link    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129345/unmarshal-ignore-empty-fields

Comment: can you share the code of update operations

Comment: Thanks!! you have to specify omitempty on the sturct and convert it

`var payloadInterface map[string]interface{}
 inrec, _ := json.Marshal(payload)

 json.Unmarshal(inrec, &payloadInterface)`

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify omitempty on the struct

```
type PayloadUpdateProfile struct {
    FullName    string       `json:"fullName,omitempty" bson:"fullName,omitempty"`
    FirstName   string       `json:"firstName,omitempty" bson:"firstName,omitempty"`
    LastName    string       `json:"lastName,omitempty" bson:"lastName,omitempty"`
}
```

Bind the payload into the struct as usual

```
var payload profile.PayloadUpdateProfile
err := c.Bind(&payload)
```

then convert it

```
var payloadInterface map[string]interface{}
    inrecPayload, _ := json.Marshal(payload)

    json.Unmarshal(inrec, &payloadInterface)

UpdateMethod(ctx, filter, payloadInterface)
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can do things like this:

```
    type updatePayload struct {
    FullName    string `json:"fullName" bson:"fullName"`
    FirstName   string `json:"firstName" bson:"firstName"`
    LastName    string `json:"lastName" bson:"lastName"`
    Location    string `json:"location" bson:"location"`
    Gender      string `json:"gender" bson:"gender"`
    State       string `json:"state" bson:"state"`
    Subdistrict string `json:"subdistrict" bson:"subdistrict"`
    Address     string `json:"homeAddress" bson:"homeAddress"`
    Profession  string `json:"provession" bson:"provession"`
    Settings    struct {
        Email bool `json:"email" bson:"email"`
        SMS   bool `json:"sms" bson:"sms"`
        GCM   bool `json:"gcm" bson:"gcm"`
    } `json:"settings" bson:"settings"`
    Coordinates struct {
        Type        string    `json:"type" bson:"type"`
        Coordinates []float64 `json:"coordinates" bson:"coordinates"`
    } `json:"coordinates" bson:"coordinates"`
}

func (payload *updatePayload) prepareUpdateQuery() (bson.M, error) {
    updateQuery := make(bson.M)
    if len(payload.FirstName) != 0 {
        updateQuery["firstName"] = payload.FirstName
    }

    if len(payload.LastName) != 0 {
        updateQuery["lastName"] = payload.LastName
    }
    // do same like above for other fields 

    updateQ := make(bson.M)
    updateQ["$set"] = updateQuery
    return updateQ, nil
}
```

> have the method on updatePayload struct and after decoding the api payload , call this method and generate the update query for those fields only which has data from api payload. Once update query is made pass that update query to mongodb update wrapper function .